# Video mirroring wf-recorder

Tags: linux, wayland

I am trying to horizontally flip the video flux that is recorded by wf-recorder.
I am recording it like so:
`wf-recorder --muxer=v4l2 --codec=rawvideo --pixel-format=yuv420p --file=/dev/video2`

How could I flip the video output which is redirected to /dev/video2 ?

Comment: according to [wf-recorder git issue](https://github.com/ammen99/wf-recorder/issues/90#issuecomment-620703312). It only looks mirrored to the person running the wf-recorder. To people on the other side of the stream, it looks normal.